# Matlab: Computations with the translations of a function

Tags: matlab, function, loops

Before the question, thank you for reading this post.

1. I have defined a real function, `f= @(x) sin(x) + x.^2` and I want to store the N translates of f from 0 to N-1, in a vector w. I mean, I want to store the vector  `w=( sin(x) + x.^2 , ...., sin(x- (N-1)) + (x-(N-1)).^2)`
2. I have a vector, `v`, of `N` real numbers.
3. Question: How to get the inner product, `u`, of `v` and `w`? I want to store it as a function because I want to calculate the FFT coefficients of `u`.

I'm trying to do this with a loop but I'm making a mess with the loop/s.

Would you help me, please?
Many thanks.

What I did with the help of @m7913d:

```
%%%code
N=10;
v=rand(1,N);%%vector
tras=1:N;
tsi=t.*ones(1,N);
%%ff(x)=sin(x)+x.^2
ff=sin(tsi+tras) +(tsi+tras).^2 ;
total=sum(ff.*v,2);
vpa(subs(total,t,0.1));%%check
Fs=100;% Sampling frequency
tt=-pi:1/Fs:pi;% Time vector 
L=length(tt);  % Signal length
X=double(subs(total, t,tt));
n=2^nextpow2(L);
coef=fft(X,n);
```

Comment: Why do you need a function handle to calculate an FFT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved. Here is the code

```
%%%code
N=10;
v=rand(1,N);%%vector
tras=1:N;
tsi=t.*ones(1,N);
%%ff(x)=sin(x)+x.^2
ff=sin(tsi+tras) +(tsi+tras).^2 ;
total=sum(ff.*v,2);
vpa(subs(total,t,0.1));%%check
Fs=100;% Sampling frequency
tt=-pi:1/Fs:pi;% Time vector 
L=length(tt);  % Signal length
X=double(subs(total, t,tt));
n=2^nextpow2(L);
coef=fft(X,n);
```

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a cell array of functions as follows:

```
N = 10;
f= @(x) sin(x) + x.^2;
u = cell(N, 1);
v = rand(N, 1);
g = 0;
for i=0:(N-1)
    u{i+1} = @(x) v(i+1)*f(x + i);
    g = @(x) g(x) + u{i+1}(x);
end
```

Note that I calculated the `u` vector at once, without using the intermediate variable `w`.

Note that the calculations will be easier (and faster) if you immediately insert your desired `x` vector. In that case, you do not have to hassle with function handles.